# Some community user can't post on chatter, while admin user can

Tags: community, chatter

in my org if I log in to the community as a system admin I am able to see post option whereas another community user can only see chatter feed and an option to comment on posts but can't see the option to post to chatter. Can anyone provide a resolution to this? 
Also, I want to point that the user can post on any account's record's chatter but not on any other object's record.

Comment: I found the answer to this. when you add feed publisher on community page you need to select whether you want the post to be global or related to a record. If you select a "record" then it won't be available for community user.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

I resolved by adding on Community the `Feed` component that shows the chatter feed and also the `Feed Publisher` component to post/start conversation on chatter (related to a record option worked for me).

I have to note that Community is configured for Partner Community users.

Hope this helps.